# Categorize dataframe by percentile in R

Tags: r, percentile

I have following data:

```
set.seed(15)
ddf <- data.frame(
    gp1 = sample(1:3, 200, replace=T), 
    gp2 = sample(c('a','b'), 200, replace=T), 
    param = sample(10:20, 200, replace=T) 
)
head(ddf)
  gp1 gp2 param
1   2   a    18
2   1   b    11
3   3   a    15
4   2   b    20
5   2   a    17
6   3   b    11
```

I have to create another column called 'category' which needs to have a value of 1 if 'param' for that row is more than 75th percentile for that gp1 and gp2.

I tried following but I am not sure if this is correct:

```
ddf$category = with(ddf, ifelse(param>quantile(ddf[ddf$gp1==gp1 & ddf$gp2==gp2,]$param, .75, na.rm=T), 1, 0)  )
```

Is above code correct or else how can this be done? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can ecdf() (or Ecdf() of Hmisc) be used here?

Comment: Probably not.  `ecdf` and `quantile` are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(After changing "value" to "param")

```
ddf = data.frame(gp1, gp2, param)
ddf$category <- with(ddf, ave(param, gp1,gp2, 
                             FUN=function(x) x > quantile(x,.95) ) )
> ddf
    gp1 gp2 param category
1     2   a    20        0
2     2   a    16        0
3     1   a    12        0
4     1   b    16        0
5     3   b    19        0
 snipped

> sum(ddf$category)
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I find the output of this is different from the output of my code. My code must be wrong but where is the error there?

Comment: Also can I safely add na.rm=TRUE to your code? Finally, why is your code producing 0 and 1 values and not TRUE and FALSE?

Comment: @rnso You can just use `as.logical` or `!!ave(.. `

Comment: @akrun : So ave gives numeric output. @ BondedDust: We can do with 75th percentile for more values of 1.

Comment: You certainly could use an `na.rm=TRUE` in the quantile arguments. I don't understand the concern about it being numeric, since that was what you requested. And yes, as you lower the threshold the number of 1's will increase.

Comment: I just did not know that ave gives numeric output. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't know it would do that either and I still don't know why after looking at the help pages and the code. Feel free to ask another question :-)

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Why is my code wrong? It is giving result different from yours. I tried after getting more values of 1 by using 75 rather than 95 percentile.

Comment: Your code is not doing any grouping for the calculation of the quantile. Every 'param' is being checked against just one quantile.